# Website Performance Issue

Tags: performance, web

If a website is experiencing performance issues all of a sudden, what can be the reasons behind it?
According to me database can one reason or space on server can be one of few reasons, I would like to know more about it.

Comment: Looks like a homework question to me.

Comment: You are going to get super specific answers. The information you provided is more than enough to pinpoint the problem EXACTLY

Comment: I am newbie. So just wanted to know more for better understanding.

Comment: I am reluctant to answer, because this seems like someone asking for help with their homework. I encourage your intellectual curiosity, but perhaps try with something like googling "things that affect server performance"

Comment: What kind of performance issues. When it comes to a website, "performance" issues can be related to js, css, images, network, application server, physical server, cpu, memory, space, or even application logic causing perceived performance issues.

Comment: the reason why your website has performance issues is because of global warming.  as the earth warms up, servers tend to slow down 'causing noticeable decrease in website performance.

Comment: Performance issue related to database and query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There can be n number of reasons and n depends on your specification**

According to what you have specified you can have a look at,

1. System counters of webserver/appserver like cpu, memory, paging, io, disk
2. What changes you did to application if any, were those changes performance costly i.e. have a round of analysis on those changes to check whether any improvement is required.
3. If system counters are choking then check which one is bottleneck and try to resolve it.
4. Check all layers/tiers of application i.e. app server, database, directory etc. 
   if database is bottleneck then identify costly queries and apply indexes & other DB tuning 
   If app server is choking then, you need to identify & improve the method which is resource heavy.

Performance tuning is not a fast track process, it takes time, identify bottlenecks and try to solve it and repeat the process until you get desired performance.

Comment: Thanks what are other DB tuning ways apart from indexes

Comment: partitioning, data fetching sizes, avoid locking, write efficient queries, tune collection pool size etc. depends on situation which one to apply.